# Indirect speech for :"He predicted the success of the invention several years before it was perfected."?

Tags: reported-speech

I am not sure about the right version of the reported speech for this sentence:

Direct speech:

> An affirmation made by an author: "*W. Thomson **predicted** the success of the invention several years before it **was perfected**.*"

Reported speech:

> 1. An author wrote that W. Thomson **had predicted** the success of the invention several years before it **was perfected**.
> 2. An author wrote that W. Thomson **had predicted** the success of the invention several years before it **had been perfected**.
> 3. An author wrote that W. Thomson **predicted** the success of the invention several years before it **was perfected**. (unchanged)

Another question: Is "before it was perfected" a subjunctive in English or not?

Comment: The right choice should be #2. Wait, what made you think it's a subjunctive?

Comment: Regarding "what made me think it was a subjunctive", I simply translated "before it was perfected" in another language and remarked that a subjunctive offers the best translation.

Comment: #2 is least likely, IMO, since the two past perfect verbs just get in each other's way and don't establish a reference time to show the sequence of events.  #1 is my first choice, with #3 as an acceptable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three answers could be fine.  I'm really not all that familiar with the so-called "rules" around backshifting reported speech, but I think they're mostly useful guides to get started and not actual grammatical requirements.

In this case there is no real *need* for the perfect tense, so the simple past is sufficient -- but as long as you use the grammar correctly, there's no rule *against* using the past perfect or past perfect continuous.  Silly example:

> She had told me that she had had a haddock, but she hadn't had.

As for your second question, I don't see how "before it was perfected" would be the subjunctive, since it seems a simple statement of fact.  To make the subjunctive in this context possibly involves jumping through a lot of hoops, something like, "before it was to have been perfected."

Comment: I wasn't going to read this answer, but then I did just for the halibut.